# Select IDs which do not JOIN

Tags: sql

I want to get the list of `ProductId` which has not been ordered by an `Employee`.

I have this query which gives me all `ProductId` which has been ordered, but I want reverse of it:

```
SELECT distinct e.EmployeeID ,p.ProductID 
FROM Products p JOIN OrderDetails od 
  ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID JOIN Orders o 
  ON o.OrderID=od.OrderID JOIN Employee e 
  ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
order by e.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Can you please provide your query, which was doesn't give expected output?

Comment: Show some sample data and the output you are expecting.

Comment: select distinct e.EmployeeID ,p.ProductID from Products p 
  join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID
 join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
 join Employee e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID order by e.EmployeeID

Comment: it gives the products ordered by employees but want which or not ordered

Comment: If a product doesnt exist in orderdetails table, that is not ordered by employee. did you get that?

Comment: no can u explain with query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but if you want products without Employee associated you can try this :

```
SELECT distinct e.EmployeeID ,p.ProductID 
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od 
    ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Orders o 
    ON o.OrderID=od.OrderID 
LEFT JOIN Employee e 
    ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
WHERE e.EmployeeID is NULL
order by e.EmployeeID
```

The idea is to select all the orders (INNER JOIN) also orders who haven't Employee associated (LEFT JOIN). Finally you filter on those which haven't association (IS NULL).

Comment: `WHERE e.EmployeeID is NULL` the only employee id that's going to return - is null